# Add text/content on rectangle HERE maps

Tags: here-api

I want to add some text on the rectangle on here maps. I`ve already tried this:

```
    var obj = new H.map.Rect(boundingBox, {
    style: {
        fillColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        lineWidth: 3,
        content: 'fsd'
    },
});
```

but 'content' property in this case does nothing. Is it possible to add text or content on rectangle in HERE maps?

Answer (score 1):

For this case we would recommend to use H.map.Overlay (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-overlay.html) object that gives you option to put arbitrary bitmap within the given bounding box. So you can use the HTML canvas to draw text and then H.map.Overlay to put it on the map.